# WF4: Persistance and DTC

Tags: transactions, workflow, persistence, workflow-foundation-4, msdtc

I'm building a workflow host that will manage [WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx) instances.

Instances will use SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

Tables and logic for SqlWorkflowInstanceStore are in the same database as my other tables and logic that I'm writing into with persistence participants.

I'm not using AppFabric.

**My question is: do I need DTC running ?**

Note: In WF3/3.5 for the same configuration DTC was needed (don't know exactly why, seems odd because there is only one server and database).

Answer (score 1):

You will be creating multiple connections to the same database and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394702/multiple-connections-with-same-connection-string-under-a-single-transaction-elev) article that does still elevate the transaction to the DTC.